# Unmanaged Library but required for running the application

Tags: sbt

I come across the link - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html

I want to have a library in lib folder. However i want this to get added during running application as well. Currently compiling works fine but running causing issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with an example. Also follow these [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when defining one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether your dependencies are managed (i.e. published and fetched by the build tool) or not (jars that you put in a local folder), if you want to run your application without the build tool, you will either need to provide a full classpath (pointing the JVM to all dependencies), or package it together with the dependencies. There are several ways to do it. Here are a couple of common sbt plugins for that purpose:

- [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) lets you build application packages in various native formats
- [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) creates an über JAR of your project with all of its dependencies